# Unity v5.9.5 upgrade missed types

Tags: c#, unity-container

Hi I had upgraded an WPF application to Unity v5.9.5

And now I have the following missed types

```
UnityConfigurationSection
InjectionParameterValue
IResolverPolicy
IBuilderContext
ConstructorArgumentResolveOperation
```

This are the current packages included in my project

```
  <package id="Unity" version="5.9.5" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="4.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Container" version="5.9.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.RegistrationByConvention" version="5.9.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

What packages are missed to install to resolve the missing types?

BR

Comment: I have the same issue.  There appears to be a lot ofchanges to the Unity API, but I can't find any upgrade guides!

Comment: I've started an issue on the Unity project: https://github.com/unitycontainer/abstractions/issues/97